# Using npm's request package, how should you pass data originally held in a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, request

I'm using npm's request and I'm working with an API.
The API request over CURL required that I send information through a file using @site.json.

Example:

```
curl -X POST -d @site.json 'https://api.xxxxxxx.com/site?id=123456’
```

Here's the main part of my code:

```
let data = JSON.stringify(`{"placement":{"name":"${placementName}"}}`);

fs.writeFile('placement.json', JSON.parse(data), (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
})

fs.createReadStream('placement.json').pipe(request(options));
// clear the file for next placement
fs.truncate('placement.json', 0, () => {console.log('done')})
```

So I am able to build what I need to using this code and a function I created to make sure no duplicates are created. The problem is that I need to run the script multiple times in order to get all the "placements" built.

I am guessing it's the fs package and it's not working fast enough or failing on writing the file at times. I can see the .json file and sometimes the data is not cleared (but is overwritten) and sometimes the code does not update when it should.

Is there a way to pass this json data through using "request" if it originally was contained in a file? I searched the documentation but haven't found the answer yet.

I've tried a few ways in options like using json, data, forms, and the API doesn't seem to recognize the information sent in that way. Is there another way I should try?

My options:

```
const options = {
    url: `https://api.xxxxxxxxxx.com/placement?id=${publisherId}`, 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token
    }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: how about if you use promise?

Comment: Thanks @NavidYousefzai, I actually already do in other parts of my script but I'm not sure how I would in this case. It's always code 200 and sometimes there is code in the file and sometimes there isn't. Also, sometimes the fs to clear the file doesn't seem to do it's job. Not sure what I would use as the trigger for resolving the promise. - Yet.

Comment: I'd like to add, that's why i started looking to see if I could pass the info the api required through the request library instead of through a file. - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer, so the json data or any data that was part of a file, can be passed through options.

I used the body option. I tried that last night but for some reason, it didn't work.

I probably missed a step but needed to stringify and then parse the JSON data in order to have the api recognize the code correctly.
Now all my actions are done when they are needed on the first call.

```
body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`{"placement":{"name":"${placementName}"}}`))
```

Thanks

Edit: So this ended up working.

```
body: `{"placement":{"name":"${placementName}"}}`
```

I am thinking that Request handles all the parse / stringify should it be needed in the data you pass through options. Didn't have to declare JSON either. This is a game changer for me as I don't have to use fs in many parts of my code now.

Thanks for the comments guys.

Answer (score 2):

The `fs.writeFile` is asynchronous function which means if you want to work with the file you need to do it inside its callback which is called after the file was writen to disk, that's where you have `if (err) console.log(err);`.

But i think that you don't need to write the file to disk at all.

You can simply pass the data directly to request like this:

```
var request = require('request');

const options = {
    url: `https://api.xxxxxxxxxx.com/placement?id=${publisherId}`, 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token
    },
    json: true,
    body: { placement: { name: placementName } }
};

request(options, function callback(error, response, body) {
     //...
});
```

I haven't tried the code, though.

Comment: Hi @Molda, you were correct, I had tried this last night but it didn't work. I saw your comment and tried again without the parse stringify in my answer above ... Request takes care of it so it worked like a charm. I don't know why it didn't work last night but this is a game changer for my interface to the api ... Thanks for the help!